# Is the rx (rxjs) fromEvent operator multicast?

Tags: rxjs

Hot/Cold/Multicast can be confusing. I think I'm getting my head around it now, but I wanted to confirm that I understand properly.

[Looking at the source for rxjs's implementation for fromEvent](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/fromevent.js#L104), the constructor calls `.publish().refCount()`. Does this mean that the event listener I set up using `fromEvent`, for instance `fromEvent(document, 'click')` will only be added to the document if there is a subscriber, and once I remove all subscribers, the event listener is also removed? I am concerned about performance and want a single source stream to be multicasted to all subscribers. I believe I understand this correctly but would love some clarification if I'm not getting it. It seems like this *should* be the default case.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually using RxJS 4? Or are you using RxJS 5? The latter's source is actually [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/FromEventObservable.ts#L178-L241)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting question I never thought to test!

Speaking of tests, RxJS's tests show that it is intended that a listener is only added upon subscription, and removed when no subscriptions remain:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/test-file/spec-js/observables/fromEvent-spec.js.html#lineNumber48

And a quick test in the browser confirms it. Have play with this snippet with the dev tools open:

```js
const subs = []

const panel$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.getElementById('target'), 'click')

function add() {
  subs.push(panel$.subscribe(() => console.log('click')))
  console.log('subscribe')
}

function clearEm() {
  subs.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe())
  console.log('unsubscribe')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js">
</script>

<button id="target">Target</button>
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="clearEm()">Clear</button>
```

Here's what the debugger shows, when you right click on the target button and look at its list of attached event listeners. You might need to hit the debugger's refresh button to see the up-to-date list.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I came to the same conclusion using a test where I piped calls into tap(). But this is more accurate. Thanks!